# binding a listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have 4 list boxes and I have a DB as EMP with table tab1 and columns Name,EmpId, Salary ...

So I want to display salary in one of the list boxes. How do I do it???

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connec);
string insert_query = "select Salary from tab1";
con.Open();
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_query, con);
    int exe = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    ListBox3.DataSource = ds;
    ListBox3.DataBind();
 }
```

Is this the way? I have some problems like the items are not been displayed in the list boxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListBox3.DataSource = ds;
ListBox3.DataTextField = "Salary";
ListBox3.DataValueField = "EmpID";
ListBox3.DataBind();
```

you need to specify this before.

Comment: thank u but its not giving me any error but nothin is been displayed in listbox .. so where should i place d code right now it in pageload

Comment: it is ok in page load. Just put in if(!ispostback)//yourcode. The issue is you need to specifiy the TextField & ValueField only.

Comment: well i gave it but its nor working is thr neting wrng in my query

Comment: select salary,empID from ur table

Answer (score 3):

your code is right but u need to include some thing like this before binding..

```
Listbox3.Datasource=ds; 
Listbox.DataTextField="Salary"
Listbox.DataValueField="EmpId"
Listbox3.Databind();
```

Comment: hey thx tis code is working but wr should i place tis code?? right now in pageload n listbox is empty

Comment: u forgot to get the EmpId from DB.change the query as "Select Salary,EMP id from tab1"

Comment: hey bro its working now i had a prob with ma query thx for the help

Comment: ur welcome man..if u think my answer helped u just accept it and give me an upvote:)